# Why can't I plot this? (Python-Soccer field)

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I'm currently trying to plot onto a soccer field all the passes delivered during a game and have written some code to do so. I was able to perfectly plot every shot (code below), but now I'm trying to plot the passes and it's not working. Could you please help me find my mistake? Thank you

This is the code where I'm currently stuck. This code plots all the shots made during a game and prints a soccerfield with circles representing each shot.

```
#Creation of the Field with pre-stablished Length and Width
(fig,ax) = createPitch(pitchLengthX,pitchWidthY,'yards','gray')


for i,shot in shots.iterrows():
    x=shot['location'][0]
    y=shot['location'][1]
    
    goal=shot['shot_outcome_name']=='Goal'
    team_name=shot['team_name']
    
    circleSize=2
    circleSize=np.sqrt(shot['shot_statsbomb_xg'])*15

    if (team_name==home_team_required):
        if goal:
            shotCircle=plt.Circle((x,pitchWidthY-y),circleSize,color="red")
            plt.text((x+1),pitchWidthY-y+1,shot['player_name']) 
        else:
            shotCircle=plt.Circle((x,pitchWidthY-y),circleSize,color="red")     
            shotCircle.set_alpha(.2)
    elif (team_name==away_team_required):
        if goal:
            shotCircle=plt.Circle((pitchLengthX-x,y),circleSize,color="blue") 
            plt.text((pitchLengthX-x+1),y+1,shot['player_name']) 
        else:
            shotCircle=plt.Circle((pitchLengthX-x,y),circleSize,color="blue")      
            shotCircle.set_alpha(.2)
    ax.add_patch(shotCircle)
    
    
plt.text(5,75,away_team_required + ' shots') 
plt.text(80,75,home_team_required + ' shots') 
     
fig.set_size_inches(10, 7)
fig.savefig('Output/shots.pdf', dpi=100) 
plt.title("Tiros del "+home_team_required+" vs "+away_team_required)
plt.show()
```

This,on the other hand, is the code I use for plotting the passes on the field. I'm using the same function to draw the field and I did some adjustments to the previous function.

```
passes = df.loc[df['type_name'] == 'Pass'].set_index('id')

name_passes = "Sweden Women's"
for i,i_pass in passes.iterrows():
    x=i_pass['location'][0]
    y=i_pass['location'][1]
        
    if (i_pass['team_name']==name_passes):
        passCircle=plt.Circle((x,pitchWidthY-y),2,color="red")
        passCircle.set_alpha(.2)
        ax.add_patch(passCircle)
    
    
plt.text(5,75,name_passes+' shots') 
     
fig.set_size_inches(10, 7)
fig.savefig('Output/shots.pdf', dpi=100) 
plt.title("Pases de "+name_passes)
plt.show()
```

The output of the fisrt function is as follows:
[A map with all the shots of the game](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x2KLV.png)

The output of the passes function is as follows:

[A white strip with no information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/owbCp.png)

If you guys know how to solve this, I will really appreciate your help.

**EDIT: I WASN'T PROVIDING MINIMAL REPRODUCTIVE CODE AS SHIMO POINTED OUT**
This is the full code where I'm doing my plots:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

trayectoria="D:\\Semestre 3 Itam\\DAI\\Proyecto 2\\"
health=pd.read_csv(trayectoria+"Health.csv",encoding='UTF-8')
paisesH={}
listaPaisesH=["Angola","China","Mexico","Norway","Senegal"]
i=7
for p in health["TABLE 3. HEALTH"][7:209]:
    if p in listaPaisesH:
        paisesH[p]=i
    i+=1

print(paisesH)

basicInd=pd.read_csv(trayectoria+"BasicIndicators.csv",encoding='UTF-8')
paisesBI={}
listaPaisesBI=["Angola","China","Mexico","Norway","Senegal"]
i=5
for p in basicInd["Unnamed: 1"][5:207]:
    if p in listaPaisesBI:
        paisesBI[p]=i
    i+=1

print(paisesBI)

datosIMR={}
datosBSS={}
for (x,y) in paisesBI.items():
    datosIMR[x]=basicInd["Unnamed: 8"][y]

for (x,y) in paisesH.items():
    datosBSS[x]=health["Unnamed: 4"][y]
    
datosBSS_ar=[]
datosIMR_ar=[]
for x in datosBSS.keys():
    datosBSS_ar.append(int(datosBSS[x]))
    datosIMR_ar.append(int(datosIMR[x]))
    

pais=["Angola","China","Mexico","Norway","Senegal"]
plt.scatter(datosBSS_ar, datosIMR_ar,s=100, alpha=0.3, edgecolors='none')

for i,p in enumerate(pais):
    plt.annotate(p, (datosBSS_ar[i],datosIMR_ar[i]))

plt.legend()
plt.grid(True)

plt.title('Mortandad Infantil vs Uso de Sanitización Básica')
plt.xlabel('Porcentaje de la población con acceso a una Sanitización Básica')
plt.ylabel('Menores de 1 año que fallecen por cada 1000')

m, b = np.polyfit(datosBSS_ar, datosIMR_ar, 1)
x=np.array(datosBSS_ar)   
plt.plot(x, m*x + b)

plt.show()

'Histogramas'
for (x,y) in datosBSS.items():
    datosBSS[x]=int(datosBSS[x])
    
    
estadisticasBSS=datosBSS
estadisticasBSS['media']=np.mean(datosBSS_ar)
estadisticasBSS['mediana']=np.median(datosBSS_ar)
estadisticasBSS['maximo']= np.max(datosBSS_ar)
estadisticasBSS['minimo']= np.min(datosBSS_ar)
plt.bar(estadisticasBSS.keys(), estadisticasBSS.values(),width=0.95, color='g')
plt.title("Porcentaje de la población con acceso a una Sanitización Básica (%)")
plt.xlabel('Pais')
plt.ylabel('Porcentaje')
plt.xticks(rotation=90)


for (x,y) in datosIMR.items():
    datosIMR[x]=int(datosIMR[x])
estadisticasIMR=datosIMR
estadisticasIMR['media']=np.mean(datosIMR_ar)
estadisticasIMR['mediana']= np.median(datosIMR_ar)
estadisticasIMR['maximo']= max(datosIMR_ar)
estadisticasIMR['minimo']= min(datosIMR_ar)
plt.bar(estadisticasIMR.keys(), estadisticasIMR.values(),width=0.95, color='g')
plt.title("Menores de 1 año que fallecen por cada 1000")
plt.xlabel('Pais')
plt.ylabel('Cantidad de muertes por cada 1000 personas')
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
    

'Life Expectancy vs Use of basic drinking water services (%)'

trayectoria="D:\\Semestre 3 Itam\\DAI\\Proyecto 2\\"
lifeExp=pd.read_csv(trayectoria+"DemographicIndicators.csv",encoding='UTF-8')
paisesLE={}
listaPaisesLE=["Angola","China","Mexico","Norway","Senegal"]
i=7
for p in lifeExp["TABLE 6. DEMOGRAPHIC INDICATORS"][7:207]:
    if p in listaPaisesLE:
        paisesLE[p]=i
    i+=1

print(paisesLE)

health=pd.read_csv(trayectoria+"Health.csv",encoding='UTF-8')
paisesBWS={}
listaPaisesBWS=["Angola","China","Mexico","Norway","Senegal"]
i=7
for p in health["TABLE 3. HEALTH"][7:207]:
    if p in listaPaisesBWS:
        paisesBWS[p]=i
    i+=1

print(paisesBWS)


datosLE={}
datosBWS={}
for (x,y) in paisesBWS.items():
    datosBWS[x]=health["Unnamed: 1"][y]

for (x,y) in paisesLE.items():
    datosLE[x]=lifeExp["Unnamed: 15"][y]
    
datosLE_ar=[]
datosBWS_ar=[]
for x in datosBWS.keys():
    datosBWS_ar.append(int(datosBWS[x]))
    datosLE_ar.append(int(datosLE[x]))
    

pais=["Angola","China","Mexico","Norway","Senegal"]
plt.scatter(datosBWS_ar, datosLE_ar,s=100, alpha=0.3, edgecolors='none')

for i,p in enumerate(pais):
    plt.annotate(p, (datosBWS_ar[i], datosLE_ar[i]))

plt.grid(True)

plt.title('Expectativa de Vida vs Uso the servicios básicos de agua potable (%)')
plt.ylabel('Expectativa de Vida')
plt.xlabel('Uso the servicios básicos de agua potable (%)')

m, b = np.polyfit(datosBWS_ar, datosLE_ar, 1)
x=np.array(datosBWS_ar)   
plt.plot(x, m*x + b)

plt.show()

'Histogramas'
for (x,y) in datosBWS.items():
    datosBWS[x]=int(datosBWS[x])
    
    
estadisticasBWS=datosBWS
estadisticasBWS['media']=np.mean(datosBWS_ar)
estadisticasBWS['mediana']=np.median(datosBWS_ar)
estadisticasBWS['maximo']= np.max(datosBWS_ar)
estadisticasBWS['minimo']= np.min(datosBWS_ar)
plt.bar(estadisticasBWS.keys(), estadisticasBWS.values(),width=0.95, color='g')
plt.title("Uso the servicios básicos de agua potable (%)")
plt.xlabel('Pais')
plt.ylabel('Porcentaje')
plt.xticks(rotation=90)


for (x,y) in datosLE.items():
    datosLE[x]=int(datosLE[x])
    
estadisticasLE=datosLE
estadisticasLE['media']=np.mean(datosLE_ar)
estadisticasLE['mediana']= np.median(datosLE_ar)
estadisticasLE['maximo']= max(datosLE_ar)
estadisticasLE['minimo']= min(datosLE_ar)
plt.bar(estadisticasLE.keys(), estadisticasLE.values(),width=0.95, color='g')
plt.title("Expectativa de Vida")
plt.xlabel('Pais')
plt.ylabel('Años esperados de vida')
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
```

And this is the FCPython file I'm importing in order to be able to use the createPitch function:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Arc

def createPitch(length,width, unity,linecolor): # in meters

    """
    creates a plot in which the 'length' is the length of the pitch (goal to goal).
    And 'width' is the width of the pitch (sideline to sideline). 
    Fill in the unity in meters or in yards.

    """
    #Set unity
    if unity == "meters":
        # Set boundaries
        if length >= 120.5 or width >= 75.5:
            return(str("Field dimensions are too big for meters as unity, didn't you mean yards as unity?\
                       Otherwise the maximum length is 120 meters and the maximum width is 75 meters. Please try again"))
        #Run program if unity and boundaries are accepted
        else:
            #Create figure
            fig=plt.figure()
            #fig.set_size_inches(7, 5)
            ax=fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
           
            #Pitch Outline & Centre Line
            plt.plot([0,0],[0,width], color=linecolor)
            plt.plot([0,length],[width,width], color=linecolor)
            plt.plot([length,length],[width,0], color=linecolor)
            plt.plot([length,0],[0,0], color=linecolor)
            plt.plot([length/2,length/2],[0,width], color=linecolor)
            
            #Left Penalty Area
            plt.plot([16.5 ,16.5],[(width/2 +16.5),(width/2-16.5)],color=linecolor)
            plt.plot([0,16.5],[(width/2 +16.5),(width/2 +16.5)],color=linecolor)
            plt.plot([16.5,0],[(width/2 -16.5),(width/2 -16.5)],color=linecolor)
            
            #Right Penalty Area
            plt.plot([(length-16.5),length],[(width/2 +16.5),(width/2 +16.5)],color=linecolor)
            plt.plot([(length-16.5), (length-16.5)],[(width/2 +16.5),(width/2-16.5)],color=linecolor)
            plt.plot([(length-16.5),length],[(width/2 -16.5),(width/2 -16.5)],color=linecolor)
            
            #Left 5-meters Box
            plt.plot([0,5.5],[(width/2+7.32/2+5.5),(width/2+7.32/2+5.5)],color=linecolor)
            plt.plot([5.5,5.5],[(width/2+7.32/2+5.5),(width/2-7.32/2-5.5)],color=linecolor)
            plt.plot([5.5,0.5],[(width/2-7.32/2-5.5),(width/2-7.32/2-5.5)],color=linecolor)
            
            #Right 5 -eters Box
            plt.plot([length,length-5.5],[(width/2+7.32/2+5.5),(width/2+7.32/2+5.5)],color=linecolor)
            plt.plot([length-5.5,length-5.5],[(width/2+7.32/2+5.5),width/2-7.32/2-5.5],color=linecolor)
            plt.plot([length-5.5,length],[width/2-7.32/2-5.5,width/2-7.32/2-5.5],color=linecolor)
            
            #Prepare Circles
            centreCircle = plt.Circle((length/2,width/2),9.15,color=linecolor,fill=False)
            centreSpot = plt.Circle((length/2,width/2),0.8,color=linecolor)
            leftPenSpot = plt.Circle((11,width/2),0.8,color=linecolor)
            rightPenSpot = plt.Circle((length-11,width/2),0.8,color=linecolor)
            
            #Draw Circles
            ax.add_patch(centreCircle)
            ax.add_patch(centreSpot)
            ax.add_patch(leftPenSpot)
            ax.add_patch(rightPenSpot)
            
            #Prepare Arcs
            leftArc = Arc((11,width/2),height=18.3,width=18.3,angle=0,theta1=308,theta2=52,color=linecolor)
            rightArc = Arc((length-11,width/2),height=18.3,width=18.3,angle=0,theta1=128,theta2=232,color=linecolor)
            
            #Draw Arcs
            ax.add_patch(leftArc)
            ax.add_patch(rightArc)
            #Axis titles

    #check unity again
    elif unity == "yards":
        #check boundaries again
        if length <= 95:
            return(str("Didn't you mean meters as unity?"))
        elif length >= 131 or width >= 101:
            return(str("Field dimensions are too big. Maximum length is 130, maximum width is 100"))
        #Run program if unity and boundaries are accepted
        else:
            #Create figure
            fig=plt.figure()
            #fig.set_size_inches(7, 5)
            ax=fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
           
            #Pitch Outline & Centre Line
            plt.plot([0,0],[0,width], color=linecolor)
            plt.plot([0,length],[width,width], color=linecolor)
            plt.plot([length,length],[width,0], color=linecolor)
            plt.plot([length,0],[0,0], color=linecolor)
            plt.plot([length/2,length/2],[0,width], color=linecolor)
            
            #Left Penalty Area
            plt.plot([18 ,18],[(width/2 +18),(width/2-18)],color=linecolor)
            plt.plot([0,18],[(width/2 +18),(width/2 +18)],color=linecolor)
            plt.plot([18,0],[(width/2 -18),(width/2 -18)],color=linecolor)
            
            #Right Penalty Area
            plt.plot([(length-18),length],[(width/2 +18),(width/2 +18)],color=linecolor)
            plt.plot([(length-18), (length-18)],[(width/2 +18),(width/2-18)],color=linecolor)
            plt.plot([(length-18),length],[(width/2 -18),(width/2 -18)],color=linecolor)
            
            #Left 6-yard Box
            plt.plot([0,6],[(width/2+7.32/2+6),(width/2+7.32/2+6)],color=linecolor)
            plt.plot([6,6],[(width/2+7.32/2+6),(width/2-7.32/2-6)],color=linecolor)
            plt.plot([6,0],[(width/2-7.32/2-6),(width/2-7.32/2-6)],color=linecolor)
            
            #Right 6-yard Box
            plt.plot([length,length-6],[(width/2+7.32/2+6),(width/2+7.32/2+6)],color=linecolor)
            plt.plot([length-6,length-6],[(width/2+7.32/2+6),width/2-7.32/2-6],color=linecolor)
            plt.plot([length-6,length],[(width/2-7.32/2-6),width/2-7.32/2-6],color=linecolor)
            
            #Prepare Circles; 10 yards distance. penalty on 12 yards
            centreCircle = plt.Circle((length/2,width/2),10,color=linecolor,fill=False)
            centreSpot = plt.Circle((length/2,width/2),0.8,color=linecolor)
            leftPenSpot = plt.Circle((12,width/2),0.8,color=linecolor)
            rightPenSpot = plt.Circle((length-12,width/2),0.8,color=linecolor)
            
            #Draw Circles
            ax.add_patch(centreCircle)
            ax.add_patch(centreSpot)
            ax.add_patch(leftPenSpot)
            ax.add_patch(rightPenSpot)
            
            #Prepare Arcs
            leftArc = Arc((11,width/2),height=20,width=20,angle=0,theta1=312,theta2=48,color=linecolor)
            rightArc = Arc((length-11,width/2),height=20,width=20,angle=0,theta1=130,theta2=230,color=linecolor)
            
            #Draw Arcs
            ax.add_patch(leftArc)
            ax.add_patch(rightArc)
                
    #Tidy Axes
    plt.axis('off')
    
    return fig,ax
```

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Please provide minimal reproductive code. What are import modules, df, ...?

Comment: Done, thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have solved the problem. Calling the createPitch function right before the execution of the Pass code. Thanks